# Where are cached email messages stored in the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, internal-storage

Google recently disabled one of my Gmail accounts (and will apparently take several days to re-enable it), but luckily I have some emails I need right now saved in the Gmail app.

Is there any way I can download them to my computer? In what folder are they stored on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Answer (score 7):

Gmail usually stores its data on internal storage:

```
/data/data/com.google.android.gm/
├── cache
│   ├── download
│   └── webviewcache
├── databases
├── files
├── lib
└── shared_prefs
```

From this directory structure you may guess some things. I'm not sure what exactly is stored in the `cache` subdirectory except for downloads (the extracted Nandroid backup I've got on my workstation comes from a device where Gmail actually wasn't used). Your messages (in fact, your entire mail contents) are however stored in a SQLite3 database: `databases/mailstore.<address>` -- where `<address>` is your mail address.

So if you can pull this directory to your computer (which might require root privileges), you could use a graphical SQLite frontend to explore this database. The `messages` table will be your primary target.