# How to backup gmail data from android with adb

Tags: adb, backup, gmail

I have a non-gmail account with a cache of messages in my android gmail app.
**How can I make a backup of the emails and attachments?** Accessing the mail server to make a backup is not possible.
I tried the method in the answer here: [Backup gmail emails offline](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75171/backup-gmail-emails-offline)
However, the backup file is too small to realistically contain the emails and attachments. It's only coming out 549 bytes, even with trying a few different adb backup options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a backup with adb results in 41 byte file](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143367/creating-a-backup-with-adb-results-in-41-byte-file)

Comment: The GMail app has `android:allowBackup="true"` therefore app backup via adb should be possible. Try to backup a different app to test if `adb backup` works at all on your device.

Comment: Confirmed using adb 1.0.41.

Comment: Tried the methods in the above link, and was able to get a 141MB file, but it did not contain anything but manifests for most apps. gmail app database was not present. Per this link, it should be under /data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mailstore.*
Am I correct in assuming gmail is blocking the including of the mail database from adb? Do I need to root to get around this, or is there another way?
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27187/where-are-cached-email-messages-stored-in-the-gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

You can copy these files and directories and paste into new device:

1. /data/data/com.google.android.gm: for Gmail cache
2. /data/system_de/0/accounts_de.db and /data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db: for Gmail accounts and some google authentication info

maybe this method solves your problem